# I can't enter Turkish characters in console in Node js

Tags: javascript

Console in Node js I cannot enter Turkish characters

`var prompt = require('prompt-sync')();`

`global.choice = prompt(' > ');` < problem

Comment: It's rather related to the terminal you are using than node

Comment: use http://hyper.is

Comment: it does not work, the problem is not from the terminal, I can enter the normal terminal. I can't login after running node application

Comment: It works fine on my computer tho (tested just now, with a ğ and ı — although, in those unicode days, there is nothing specific to turkish: it turkish were not working, then neither would french or russian. But well, just to be sure, I tested with typically turkish letters). So, if you don't tell us more about what makes your situation different as mine, I am afraid there isn't much we can say, other that "works for me".

Comment: So, what terminal, what version of node js, what os... ? If your are using unix, what locale says?

Comment: Node.js v16.17.1  windows 11 terminal I use

Comment: I can enter the terminal directly when I open it, no problem, but not when I run the js application.

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: `var prompt = require('prompt-sync')();`

`global.choice = prompt(' > ');`

`if(choice == 1){  }`

`else if(choice == 2){  }`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.